# Show login greeting above sub-menu links?

Tags: php, menus, login, sub-menu

I'm using WordPress' built-in menu system to output my Main Menu Structure. I have one sub-menu, and it has two links currently, "Tracking" and "To-Do List". I want the following login greeting to show above those two links:

```
<?php global $current_user; if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo 'Welcome, '.$current_user->first_name.''; } else { echo 'Welcome, visitor'; } ?>
    <font id="spacer">•</font>
<?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = false ); ?>
```

The output looks like this if no one is logged in: `Welcome, visitor • Login`

How can I show this output above the two sub-menu links?

Comment: The code is correct. Can you please also put the code for the menu/submenu that you have created which includes the above code?

Comment: I'm not creating a custom menu template through code, I'm going through WordPress' menu interface: http://archondigital.com/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-menu.gif

Comment: If I am not wrong, then you want your code to reflect in the menu system as per user's login status. But I am still not sure how and where you are executing the above code.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems like you are using this modal login plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-modal-login/ Considering this, I am providing the necessary code to add the menu item to the menu.

You need to use the `wp_nav_menu_items` hook as below inside `functions.php` file of your active theme.

```
// Add the hook to the nav menu items
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wti_loginout_menu_link', 10, 2 );

function wti_loginout_menu_link( $items, $args ) {
    // Get the global object for user and the modal login class
    global $current_user, $wp_modal_login_class;

    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        $items .= '<li>';

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $items .= 'Welcome, ' . $current_user->user_nicename;
        } else {
            $items .= 'Welcome, visitor';
        }

            // Add the modal menu to the nav menu
        $items .= ' ' . $wp_modal_login_class->modal_login_btn( 'Login', 'Logout', '', false );

        $items .= '</li>';
    }

    return $items;
}
```

**Few things to note:**

- The above code works with `primary` theme location. You need to change this to your theme location.
- I am using `user_nicename`, you can use `first_name` of the user object as per your code.

The above hook is also discussed here http://www.webtechideas.com/adding-login-logout-link-to-wordpress-menu/

Comment: Thank you for the answer Chittaranjan. Could you clarify how I could insert this login info into the 'Account' sub menu? This is what my menu and the sub menu I want to insert the login info into (Account) looks like: http://i.imgur.com/KUpRybm.gif